# Select duplicate by youngest date

Tags: sql

I have run into a snag.
A got a DB with employees with multiple startdates.
Employees can start and can get a new contract later.

FE.

```
ID   NAME  DATEEMPLOYED FUNCTION
1    Paul  01/01/2016   Director
2    Paul  01/01/2015   Staff Member
3    Jeff  02/05/2016   Director
4    Jeff  01/05/2015   Employee
5    Jeff  01/05/2014   Employee
6    Eric  05/06/2015   Employee
```

Now I need to get the ID from the latest and the youngest date.
I want to copy the function of the row with the latest date to the oldest date and then delete all but the oldest.

The oldest I can find by:

```
SELECT * FROM [database].[dbo].[Personel] t WHERE DATEEMPLOYED NOT IN      (SELECT MAX(DATEEMPLOYED)  AS LastUpdate FROM [database].[dbo].[Personel] GROUP BY Naam,Voornaam)
```

This returns 10 rows...

Now to find the youngest...
I thought, it would be as easy as changing MAX(DATEEMPLOYED) to MIN(DATEEMPLOYED)...

But I guess not because this only returns 6 rows...

I'm running a live DB so no sample date...

The expected output of the query for the max date per employee is ID 1 and 3 ... The expected output for min date is ID 2 and 5 ... 
No number 6

I'am running MS SQL trough an ASP.net application...
The query posted I'm running on the SQL server itself for testing...
Later I'll adapt for the ASP.Net
I want to automatize the deletion of duplicate employees.

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your sample data has no column called `id`.

Comment: Please paste your expected output and Tag what version of 
RDBMS you are using like SQLserver,oracle,mysql,postgres..

Comment: I updated my question with your remarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEPENDING on your version, you could use the window function

```
    Declare @YourTable table (ID int,NAME varchar(50),  DATEEMPLOYED Date, [FUNCTION] varchar(50))
    Insert Into @YourTable values
    (1,'Paul','01/01/2016','Director'),
    (2,'Paul','01/01/2015','Staff Member'),
    (3,'Jeff','02/05/2016','Director'),
    (4,'Jeff','01/05/2015','Employee'),
    (5,'Jeff','01/05/2014','Employee'),
    (6,'Eric','05/06/2015','Employee')


;with cteBase as (
    Select Distinct Name 
          ,Times   = count(*) over  (Partition By Name) 
          ,MinID   = min(ID) over (Partition By Name) 
          ,MaxID   = max(ID) over (Partition By Name) 
          ,MinDate = min(DATEEMPLOYED) over  (Partition By Name Order By DATEEMPLOYED) 
          ,MaxDate = max(DATEEMPLOYED) over  (Partition By Name Order By DATEEMPLOYED Desc) 
     From @YourTable
)
Select * from cteBase where Times>1
```

Returns

```
Name    Times   MinID   MaxID   MinDate     MaxDate
Jeff    3       3       5       2014-01-05  2016-02-05
Paul    2       1       2       2015-01-01  2016-01-01
```

Comment: Hi, your query looks great... Only problem it is also showing non duplicates like Eric... MY Db contains 3000 items so be a big list.

Comment: @BE_Joachim Got a little lost in your requirements.  Updated answer to nested under cte

Comment: Thanks man, i think I can make the original work... I'll just put an if clause in there and try it... Offcourse if you could make it nested, it would be even more gratefull :) Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Does your DB have NULL dates, if so you need to check for those.

Comment: No nulls in the DB